# Is it possible to rename a table in the middle of a clustered index rebuild?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

This really feels like a bad idea, but we have very large table which is currently rebuilding an index, I don't want to stop the rebuild, but we need to change the table name from dbo.My_Table_New to dbo.My_Table.  Thoughts?

Comment: I think it will just block waiting for a `Sch-M` lock anyway. (i.e. it isn't possible)

Answer (score 3):

No.

What are you expecting??  Wait for it to finish, then go for it.

To check, you can start a new session and run

```
sp_lock 52
```

(if 52 is the process doing the index rebuild).  You will see among the locks

```
spid  objid     type   mode   resource
52    27147142  TAB    X
52    0         MD     Sch-S  1(19e3b86:0:0)
```

Where

- object_name(27147142) gives you the table being restructured,
- X is the exclusive lock
- Sch-S is a schema stability lock, preventing any changes to schema (on the page related to the table)

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea...
Create a view, use the view, then when you can rename, delete the view.

Comment: Good, except he won't be able to select from it anyways while the index is running.

Comment: Oh well, worth a shot - just a guess.  Wouldn't an online rebuild of the index work?  Or do I not know something about views and their interaction with the basetable when being rebuilt?

Comment: @Sam - it's because it's a clustered index as specified in the title (but not in the body of the post).

Comment: Docs on the ONLINE parameter of the ALTER INDEX statement don't specify clustered indexes failing to be covered by the ONLINE option, only if they contain LOB.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx  Hmmm...

Comment: @Sam - actually if you read more closely the index rebuild applies a Schema-M lock, which blocks concurrent access.  Try it on your server and see if you can query your table.

Comment: @JNK - Good catch there - I'll have to look into this.  Don't really understand the benefit of an ONLINE rebuild since it specifies that the table will be locked for clustered and non-clustered indexes.